# Fatal Error : Could not Access the Global Configuration part in Administration

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, administrator, global-configuration

I have Installed Joomla 3.3 on My site through FTP and have created database for the Site with the User.I successfully installed the site but I'm not able to access the Global Configuration part on the administrator part
I am getting the error message

```
Fatal error: Class 'ConfigModelForm' not found in /home/**path**/administrator/components/com_config/model/application.php in Line 20
```

I have tried the `Jcache` to remove the cache problems and also tried adding the file **application.php** again but could not resolve it.

What should I do ?

Comment: Update Joomla ! Works like a charm !

Answer (score 2):

I would re-install the site from scratch. Something must have gone wrong in the initial installation.